# Do Browsers implement the HTTP protocol?

Tags: http, tcpip

My understanding of the TCP/IP stack is that the Application layer (layer 4) consists of protocol implementations such as HTTP.

Do user-agents like web browsers implement this HTTP protocol themselves? i.e. Is the user-agent itself responsible for formatting the data package to conform with the HTTP protocol and then passing the message onto the Transport layer? Or does the user-agent pass the request data to a specific system application on the OS that implements the HTTP protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For example: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack.

That's why some browsers support some features (e.g. Http/2) and some do not.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is the responsibility of the application, or some library it uses.

**You can see how it is all put together by looking at some code**

Like this http://search.cpan.org/~ether/HTTP-Message-6.11/lib/HTTP/Request.pm

And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java

**HTTP is layer 7**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_(OSI_model)

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, When I stated that the Application layer was layer 4 I was referring to the TCP/IP model, rather than the OSI model. Is this bad form on my behalf?

Comment: @b73 Oh I see. You are correct. I am just so familiar with people talking about the OSI model.